# How to call await inside mocha root hook plugin

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js

I am using the mocha root hook plugin as this piece of code:

```
exports.mochaHooks = {
    beforeEach(done) {
        some code
        done();
    },
 };
```

But now I need to await an async function inside the beforeEach block. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The syntaxis is as follow:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
    await doSomething()
})
```